# how to convert int to void *?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to make an analogue of `sscanf` with a specifier `%p`.

I use this:

```
int res = ahex2num(buf);
*va_arg(ap, void **) = (void *) res;
```

It works correctly, i actually get the address i pass, like `0x1A` but i am facing this error:

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

In main function:

```
int main(){
    void *a;
    readFromStr("0x1A", "%p", &a);
    printf("%p", a); 
    return 0;
}

/*
out: 0x1a
*/
```

Can I somehow avoid this?

```
long ahex2num(unsigned char *in){
    unsigned char *pin = in;
    long out = 0;
    while(*pin != 0){
        out <<= 4;
        out +=  (*pin < 'A') ? *pin & 0xF : (*pin & 0x7) + 9;
        pin++;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: show your ahex2num() function

Comment: Andrey, `ahex2num()` returns a `long` yet code `int res = ahex2num(buf);` saves in an `int`.  Why the type change?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently pointers, particularly `void *`, have a different size than `int` on your system. E.g., pointers may be 64 bits and `int` may be 32 bits. Implementing `%p` in a routine like `sscanf` is a valid reason for converting an integer to `void *`, but you need to use an integer type that can hold all the bits needed for a pointer. A good type for this may be `uintptr_t`, declared in `<stdint.h>`.

You will need to ensure all the code that works with the integers from the scanning, such as `ahex2num`, can support the necessary width and signedness, including handling potential overflow as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If I had your entire code, I could test it.  I assume to remove the warning without using a pragma is as simple as changing your typecast from int to long int.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
long long int res = ahex2num(buf);
```

Comment: `ahex2num()` returns a `long`.  Why save the return value in a `long long` instead of a `long`?